# how to add support for character set IBM437 to J2SE 1.4 API

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, encoding, character-encoding

I have to make changes to an old project which uses J2SE 1.4. Now as I run the project I get the error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: The character set 'IBM437' is supported by the JSE 1.1 API, but not the J2SE 1.4 API.
This requires fixing the Java Runtime Environment!
Please read the Javadoc of this error class for more information.
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:498)
    at org.apache.jsp.download_orders_action_jsp._jspService(download_orders_action_jsp.java:131)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:92)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:720)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:162)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:240)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:187)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:720)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:955)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:955)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.invoke(StandardContext.java:2460)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorDispatcherValve.invoke(ErrorDispatcherValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:955)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:596)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:955)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat4.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:157)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:873)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:534)
```

It is being used by a zip file creator. M question is how can I add this support to J2SE 1.4. Googling the problem got me to [this](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas210a998609b4ef13e86257024003cc251) page , but i dont get what to do from this page. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

code for making the zip files , which is being called from the jsp and where i think the real problem is

```
String zipFilename = currentDumpDirName + ".zip";
de.schlichtherle.io.File srcDir = new de.schlichtherle.io.File(currentDumpRootDir);
de.schlichtherle.io.File zipFile = new de.schlichtherle.io.File(dumpRootDir, zipFilename);
boolean zippedSuccessfully = srcDir.copyAllTo(zipFile);
zipFile.umount();
```

as one can see from the root cause of the exception

> de.schlichtherle.io.archive.spi.AbstractArchiveDriver$InconsistentCharsetSupportError: The character set 'IBM437' is supported by the JSE 1.1 API, but not the J2SE 1.4 API.
>   This requires fixing the Java Runtime Environment!
>   Please read the Javadoc of this error class for more information.
>       at de.schlichtherle.io.archive.spi.AbstractArchiveDriver.(AbstractArchiveDriver.java:92)
>       at de.schlichtherle.io.archive.zip.Zip32Driver.(Zip32Driver.java:136)
>       at de.schlichtherle.io.archive.zip.Zip32Driver.(Zip32Driver.java:71)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:274)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:308)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:261)
>       at de.schlichtherle.io.ArchiveDriverRegistry.createArchiveDriver(ArchiveDriverRegistry.java:267)
>       at de.schlichtherle.io.ArchiveDriverRegistry.getArchiveDriver(ArchiveDriverRegistry.java:240)
>       at de.schlichtherle.io.DefaultArchiveDetector.getArchiveDriver(DefaultArchiveDetector.java:324)
>       at de.schlichtherle.io.File.init(File.java:892)
>       at de.schlichtherle.io.File.init(File.java:810)
>       at de.schlichtherle.io.File.(File.java:556)
>       at de.schlichtherle.io.File.(File.java:522)
>       at uk.co.planetbeyond.photoprintingserver.OrdersPackagingService.packageOrders(OrdersPackagingService.java:43)
>       at org.apache.jsp.download_orders_action_jsp._jspService(download_orders_action_jsp.java:118)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:92)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:720)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:162)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:240)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:187)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:720)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:199)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:145)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:596)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:433)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:955)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:139)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:596)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:433)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:955)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.invoke(StandardContext.java:2460)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:133)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:596)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorDispatcherValve.invoke(ErrorDispatcherValve.java:119)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:594)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:116)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:594)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:433)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:955)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:127)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:596)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:433)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:955)
>       at org.apache.coyote.tomcat4.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:157)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:873)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:534)
>   Caused by: java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: IBM437
>       at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Charset.java:486)
>       at de.schlichtherle.io.archive.spi.AbstractArchiveDriver.testJSE14Support(AbstractArchiveDriver.java:112)
>       at de.schlichtherle.io.archive.spi.AbstractArchiveDriver.(AbstractArchiveDriver.java:89)
>       ... 53 more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be using `IBM437` as the canonical name or alias of the charset, and according to the [same page that you linked](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas210a998609b4ef13e86257024003cc251), it is not listed as a valid name or alias. Instead, `IBM-437` is listed, which appears to be the right name, and you ought to specify that instead.

I don't see any code posted in the question, that uses the String literal `IBM437` in code, and going by the stacktrace I suspect that you've specified this in a JSP (which gets compiled into a Servlet that uses the Jasper engine) either in the `pageEncoding` attribute or in the `contentType` attribute of the `page` directive. So, you ought to replace `IBM437` to `IBM-437` in the JSP, and recompile the same.

Also, you haven't specified whether your project must use the `IBM-437` character set. I suspect that the `IBM-437` character set is being used due to one of more system properties like `file.encoding` being set to `IBM-437`. If you do not intend to use `IBM-437`, you ought to start considering use of a canonical name or alias like UTF-8 throughout your code, so that your application does not have any misplaced assumptions about the character set of the input data or output responses that it is dealing with.

---

**Updated answer**

Based on the new stack trace and the posted code, the following could be deduced:

- You are using TrueZIP 6. This is important in a way, as the underlying reason for requiring `IBM437` character set support in your JRE is due to the [underlying requirement of encoding file entries in a ZIP file using the `IBM437` character set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106367/add-non-ascii-file-names-to-zip-in-java/200804#200804), also known as `CP437`.
- Your current JRE and *operating environment* does not support the `IBM437` character set *in any form*. Note the emphasis in the previous line. Apparently, TrueZIP 6 ships with support for `IBM437`, even though the JRE may not support this character set. TrueZIP uses the [SPI provider concept in Java NIO that is available since Java 1.4](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/spi/CharsetProvider.html) for supporting additional charsets that are not natively supported by the JRE; in this particular case, the `IBM437` character set is supported via the `de.schlichtherle.nio.charset.IBM437Charset` class that must be present in your truezip-6.jar file. The JAR file must also contain the following file: `META-INF/services/java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider` with the content being `de.schlichtherle.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider` (i.e. the charset provider embedded within TrueZIP that registers the `IBM437Charset` class).

Based on the above, you ought to verify the following:

- Can the web application's class loader look up the charset provider embedded within TrueZIP? This is important, as the underlying JRE (I'm assuming it is Sun JRE 1.4.2_x) does not support the `IBM437` character set, and TrueZIP relies on the embedded character set provider to support the `IBM437` character set. Since, `CharsetProvider`s are looked up using the current thread's context classloader (noted in the `CharsetProvider` Java API documentation), the inability to load TrueZIP's `CharsetProvider` will result in the `InconsistentCharsetSupportError` being thrown. In most web applications, the current thread's context classloader also happens to be the web application's class loader (that loads classes from `WEB-INF\lib` and `WEB-INF\classes`), but this is not necessarily true. In the event that the context classloader is not the web application classloader, you would have to place the `truezip-6.jar` file in the classpath of the context classloader instead of WEB-INF\lib.
- You may verify whether the error is with loading of the TrueZIP `CharsetProvider` implementation, by running your code in a standalone JRE (from the commandline) instead of running it in a web-application; remember to place truezip-6.jar in the classpath of the application.
- Consider placing truezip-6.jar in the extensions directory (`<jre>/lib/ext`) of the JRE used by the web-application's container. This ought to be attempted only if you are unable to get the current thread's context classloader to load the TrueZIP `CharsetProvider`, and only when you've verified that the problem is with loading the `CharsetProvider`.

Comment: Thanx for the reply but i dont think the problem is in the jsp. Actually a funtion is being called to make a zip of all the orders. I am adding the code for that in the original question. That is where the problem is, as given by the root cause, which i am also adding in the original question. Please see if u can help.

Comment: @khizar, I could deduce that you're using Truezip 6. Can you post the location of the site where you've downloaded the Truezip? I was unable to match the line numbers in the exception stack trace with the sources at the [Java.net site](http://java.net/projects/truezip/sources/v6/show).

Comment: its not my project, and its one from the archives so i dont know the site that it was downloaded from but what i can tell you is that its truezip-6.jar that is included in the project. I hope its helpful.

Comment: thanx alot vineet for such a detailed answer. i will test all cases and give the feedback.

Comment: Thanx man, i was in a hurry, so i directly tested tha third suggestion and it works like a charm.