# Wrong Character Encoding with JarOutputStream and JarEntry

Tags: java, encoding, jar, character

I'm using the class JarOutputStream to deploy a Jar from my system.
I put some files inside the jar using the class JarEntry to do it.

The problem is:
When i put a file that has some "special" characters like "Módulo de Conteúdo Local.wfre", the file goes to the JAR with the name: "M+¦dulo de Conte+¦do Local.wfre"

My original code is something like:

JarEntry jarAdd = new JarEntry(fileEntryName.replace('\', '/'));
out.putNextEntry(jarAdd);

I tried to do something like:

JarEntry jarAdd = new JarEntry(URLDecoder.decode(fileEntryName.replace('\', '/'), "UTF-8"));
out.putNextEntry(jarAdd);

But didn't worked.

Hope someone can help me :)

Comment: I found something here in stackoverflow that maybe is the path for my problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106367/add-non-ascii-file-names-to-zip-in-java